# Discord py bot that uses UUID to check a players in-game ranks (using Tebex / buycraft or luckperms)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, minecraft

I have been creating a discord python bot for a while and already have the ability to sync a minecraft UUID to a discord ID and retrieve all of this information. However, I am struggling to find information on a Tebex / buycraft API or LuckPerms API that allows me to use the MC UUID to automatically check a players in-game ranks. The end goal is for the bot to periodically check all synced discord accounts to make sure their discord ranks match the in-game ranks of the server.

Some extra details, I am using a json to store the discord ID with a corresponding minecraft UUID. I am pretty new to python but I am hoping that every like 10 or 30 minutes the bot loops through the entire json, checks each UUID for a list of their in-game ranks, if they have a specific rank add it on discord, if they have a specific rank on discord that they don't have in-game remove it on discord.

Comment: Welcome on SO ! What is your question ? Where are you stuck exactly ?

Comment: I am not sure how to create a method or something that every 30 minutes will check all accounts stored in a .json file and use their minecraft UUID to check their ranks in-game and make sure they have the corresponding ranks on the discord.

Comment: Ok but have you tried some code ? If yes, can you [edit] your question to add it ?